# How to stop main from terminating

Tags: haskell

I have this code:

```
main = do
    _ <- forkIO foo
    _ <- forkIO bar
    return ()
```

Functions `foo` and `bar` start, but terminate as soon as `main` terminates. How can I keep `main` running indefinitely, but not doing much?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `async` package nicely wraps this up as `concurrently foo bar`.

Here's a self-contained `stack` shebang script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
    --resolver lts-6.12
    --install-ghc
    runghc
    --package async
-}

import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Async

forever :: String -> Int -> IO ()
forever msg delay = loop
  where
    loop = do
      putStrLn msg
      threadDelay (delay * 1000)
      loop

foo = forever "foo" 3000
bar = forever "bar" 5000

main = foo `concurrently` bar
```

Answer (score 5):

One thing you could do is to use an `MVar ()` as a simple semaphore. Something like

```
main = do
  vFoo <- newEmptyMVar
  vBar <- newEmptyMVar
  forkIO (foo vFoo)
  forkIO (bar vBar)
  takeMVar vFoo
  takeMVar vBar

foo vFoo = do
  ...whatever...
  putMVar vFoo ()

bar vBar = do
  ...whatever...
  putMVar vBar ()
```

Comment: Might as well even reuse a single `MVar`. `do { v <- newEmptyMVar; forkIO (foo >> putMVar v ()); forkIO (bar >> putMVar v ()); takeMVar v; takeMVar v }`

Comment: You could also do that, yes. It maybe slightly increases the changes of writing the wrong number of `takeMVar` calls, or making it less obvious why there's that number of them, but for just *two* threads it's probably fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could call `getChar` so your main thread waits for input. This would also give you a convenient way to really exit the program. Or if you don't want that, just recur on the `getChar`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what behavior you want in the case that one of the two threads fails, this could be a good case for the [async](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async) package.

Functions like `race` and `concurrently` might be particularly relevant to what you're doing.